# Nucleus emitter outbound rules

Tags: mqtt, outbound, aws-iot-greengrass

I am new to green-grass and working on nucleus emitter.I have gone through the documentation but found nothing about the nucleus emitter outbound rules. I want to know the outbound rules of the nucleus emitter if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

The [Greengrass Telemetry emitter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/nucleus-emitter-component.html#nucleus-emitter-component-configuration) publishes telemetry data on local pub/sub or/and to AWS IoT Core MQTT topic.
When deploying this component to your greengrass core device, you can specify on which AWS IoT Core topic greengrass publishes telemetry. The configuration parameter is `mqttTopic`. By default it is empty.

Now, the outbound rules you mentioned is based on your greengrass configuration. By default, the port used by Greengrass for MQTT operation is 8883. Again, you can modify this port to 443  by configuring the [greengrass nucleus component](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/greengrass-nucleus-component.html#greengrass-nucleus-component-configuration). (See `mqtt` section).